# Why the webview has the gray background and smaller than the UIWebVIew

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

here is my code ,the amazon web page is smaller than the webview , and has a gray background

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

because UIWebView has extra space for status bar. you can disable status bar and extra space will hide.

in case status bar use this code to hide space:

```
[self.webView.scrollView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
```

gray color is UIWebView default background color, you can change it:

```
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```